# Error al dividir el programa de Arduino en modulos

Tags: arduino

Soy principiante en Arduino. El programa ubicado en el módulo principal funciona bien. Al dividirlo en 2 módulos aparece `error undefined reference to mp(prg)`.

En módulo ES1.h tengo

```
struct prg {     
  int n= 2;     
  char *c= "ABC";  
} Prog;
```

En módulo ES2.h tengo defino la función

```
void mp(prg p);
```

En módulo ES2.cpp tengo

```
#include "Arduino.h"  
#include "ES2.h" 
void mp(prg &p) {  
  Serial.println(p.n);  
  Serial.println(p.c);  
}
```

En módulo principal ES.ino tengo

```
#include "Es2.h"  
#include "ES1.h"  
void loop() {  
  mp(Prog);  
}
```

Comment: Parece que en el módulo principal escribiste `Es2.h` en lugar de `ES2.h`